# Unrecognised glyphs in PDF (summationdisplay, summationtext)

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-reader

I am trying to process a PDF with pdf-reader gem. It is mostly fine, but where there should be a summation symbol, I'm getting `\u0001` instead of `\u2211`. The relevant font object is:

```
{:Type=>:Font,
 :Subtype=>:Type1,
 :FirstChar=>1,
 :LastChar=>2,
 :Widths=>[1444, 1056],
 :Encoding=>{:Type=>:Encoding, :Differences=>[1, :summationdisplay, :summationtext]},
 :BaseFont=>:"APHKGN+CMEX10",
 :FontDescriptor=>
  {:Type=>:FontDescriptor,
   :Ascent=>0,
   :CapHeight=>0,
   :Descent=>0,
   :Flags=>4,
   :FontBBox=>[0, -1400, 1387, 0],
   :FontName=>:"APHKGN+CMEX10",
   :ItalicAngle=>0,
   :StemV=>47,
   :StemH=>47,
   :CharSet=>"/summationdisplay/summationtext",
   :FontFile3=>
    #<PDF::Reader::Stream:0x007faab138a528
     @data=
      "H\x89bd`ab`dd\xE4s\f\xF0\xF0v\xF7\xD3v\xF6u\x8D04\x00\x89(\xFD\x90e\xFC!\xCE\xF2C\x8EG\xACX\xE6K\x81\f\xEB\xBA\x9F3X\xBF;\xF1\x7Fw\x13\xF8\xEE%\xB8\xE2\x87\xA7\x10\x03\vP\x9F\\rfqinnbIf~^IjE\t\x9C\x93\x92Y\\\x90\x93X\xE9\x9C_PY\x94\x99\x9EQ\xA2\xA0\xE1\xAC\xA9`hii\xAE\xE0\x98\x9BZ\x94\x99\x9C\x98\xA7\xE0\x9BX\x92\x91\nR\x9D\x9C\x98\xA3\x10\x9C\x9F\x9C\x99ZR\xA9\xA7\xE0\x98\x93\xA3\x10\x04\xD2Q\xAC\x10\x94Z\x9CZT\x96\x9A\x02u\x15\xD0Y\xED\x8C\fL\x01\x11\f\xCC\x8C\x8C\xECE?\xFF3\xFA\x86\x86\xF1\xFDg\x91\xEFO\xF8Ws\xE8\x97\xECf\xC6\x1F\xD5\x7Ff\x88N\x9A\xD2\xDB\xD7/\xD5\xDF\xD5\xD3:E\xEE\xF7\xCD\x1FA\xAC?\x14\xD8\xBE\xB3}\xAFj\xF9\xED\x7FQ~\t\x9B\xE9\xF7:\xD6\xBF\x17\xD9\n\xBA\xBAr\xE4\x7F0\xFE\xE9\xFA\xFD\xFD\x8F7kscWg\xBBT\xC3\x94\xEE\xB9r?/\xB2=\xFC\xDE\xCBZ\xC4V\xE4\xE0\xE1g\x96\xC7\xD1V\xEDV\xFC[]\xFA\x8F-\e\xDF\x7F\xD6%\x85'd~u<\x92a\xF9\xB8\x9BQ\x86\xE5\x13\x90-\xFA\x9D\xF7\xFB\x15\xA0\xEA\x14eE\xF7\xDF\xEC\xB9\x1Cme\x9A\x85\xBFC\xA4\xFF\xBCg\xFB1\xF1\xC7K\xD6I\x93{\xFB&H\xF5v\xF7\xB5L\x95\xFB\x93\xF6S\x90\xF5\xC7\x0E\xB6\xEFR\xCFj;\xA7\xC8\x1Fl~Tu+rI\xF5\xF9\xB8\xB5V\x1CK\xD8~\xF3~_\xCB*\xF3;\x89\xAD\xA4\xAB\xAB\xB5C\xBE\xAB\xA3\xBB\xA2A\xEA\xC7\xD2\xBF\x19\x7Ff\xFD\xF9\xCC\xDAX\xDF\xDD\xD6\x05q _\xF9|6\x99\xDF\x95\xF3\xD9\xE5\x16\xB8O\x9D9\xE3?\x0F\xE7.\xAE]\xDC\x9B'\xF1\xF0\x001/@\x80\x01\x00J\xBC\xBFN\n",
     @hash={:Filter=>:FlateDecode, :Length=>464, :Subtype=>:Type1C},
     @udata=nil>}}
```

Since the Adobe [`glyphlist.txt`](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/opentype/glyphlist.txt) (replicated at `pdf-reader/lib/pdf/reader/glyphlist.txt`) only includes `summation`, and not `summationtext` nor `summationdisplay`, `@differences` don't get applied to `@mapping` in `PDF::Reader::Encoding#differences=`, and `@state.current_font.to_utf8(1)` fails to fetch the correct glyph (it returns the glyphcode as a fallback, which is why I end up with `\u0001`). I.e. The font mapping differences inside the PDF font object should (according to my understanding) reference glyphs on the master glyph list by name, but these two don't match.

What am I missing? If `summationdisplay` and `summationtext` are not on Adobe's `glyphlist.txt`, how do other PDF readers render this font correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defining a font subset with custom encoding and non-standard glyph names. Furthermore it does not include a `ToUnicode` reverse mapping from the custom encoding.

The [PDF-32000 Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) covers this scenario:

> 9.10 Extraction of Text Content
>
> 9.10.1 General
>
> ...
>
> When extracting character content, a conforming reader can easily convert text to Unicode values if a font’s characters are identified according to a standard character set that is known to the conforming reader. This character identification can occur if either the font uses a standard named encoding or the characters in the font are identified by standard character names or CIDs in a well-known collection. 9.10.2, "Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values", describes in detail the overall algorithm for mapping character codes to Unicode values.
>
> If a font is not defined in one of these ways, the glyphs can still be shown, but the characters cannot be converted to Unicode values without additional information:
>
> • This information can be provided as an optional ToUnicode entry in the font dictionary (PDF 1.2; see 9.10.3, "ToUnicode CMaps"), whose value shall be a stream object containing a special kind of CMap file that maps character codes to Unicode values.

`pdf-reader` does seem to be conforming to the above. There is a custom sub-set encoding with `/summationdisplay` mapped to `\u0001`. There enough information to render, but not to reverse map the font back to Unicode.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear :( but perfect answer. Thank you.